# The "node" parameter was not converted for the path "/node/{node}"

Tags: views, nodes

I have the following error in the filters with parameters in view type pages. will there be any solution to this problem?

```
Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\ParamNotConvertedException: The "node" parameter was not converted for the path "/node/{node}" (route name: "entity.node.canonical") in Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->convert() (line 104 of /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ParamConverter/ParamConverterManager.php).
```

This happens for page and block type views.

The same happens when you want to send the parameter by url

```
/index.php?q=user
```

I get the same error, it seems that the filters are not working.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Which version of Drupal/Views?  Are you using a standard install with the standard configuration?  When did this start happening?

Comment: I use drupal version 8.x.19

I am using the standard version.

I'm not really sure when this started, I just updated to its latest version, but before everything was ok;
A very clear example was in a block type view that related the news of a content that I was making displayed, it passed the content field: ID by contextual filter, but now it does not receive anything, and I get that error.

This happens for all views.

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: version of php 7.4

Comment: Check the node with that ID. has it been created from Drupal? Is it possible you are requesting a resource that hasn't been created.